# Rest Api shows error code 422 in Airtable post

Tags: c#, api, rest, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am trying to POST a record to airtable using Api
My code is

```
public async Task InsertRecord(Product2 item)
    {
        var uri = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appxxx/MainItem";
        var Api = "keyxxxx";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Api);
            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json);
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) Debug.WriteLine(@"\successfully saved.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Product2 Class has 2 fields (ItemName and Image) (MainItemId is auto)

```
public class Product2
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

When I use postman  i get this response
which is working

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "id": "reco3Scg5e1jgi8QI",
        "createdTime": "2023-03-03T14:22:08.000Z",
        "fields": {
            "MainItemId": 46,
            "Image": "https://yy.com/image/upload/t_media_lib_thumb/v1627228904/Dog.jpg",
            "ItemName": "Pet"
        }
    }
]
```

}
Ig et error code 422.
Please Help me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: [422 Unprocessable Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.

Comment: have you compared the json you are using in Postman to the json you are posting in C#?  Are you setting the same header values in both?